# Bring a view back to other iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview

I want to place a view (firstView) back to another view (secondView). SecondView is basically a barchart using CGContext.

I guess I can't use **bringViewToFront** there. So I need to place firstView back to secondView. Is there some default function to place a view back to some other view?

Comment: I want the opposite of bringToFront.

Comment: try [VIEW sendSubviewToBack:VIEW];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inverse of [`bringSubviewToFront:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW24) is [`sendSubviewToBack:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW23).

> **sendSubviewToBack:**
>
> Moves the specified subview so that it appears behind its siblings.

Another option is to use [`insertSubview:belowSubview:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW21) or [`exchangeSubviewAtIndex:withSubviewAtIndex:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/exchangeSubviewAtIndex:withSubviewAtIndex:).

Answer (score 1):

Check UIView.h

you will find all the methods Related to  `UIViewHierarchy`

Like,

```
(void)exchangeSubviewAtIndex:(NSInteger)index1 withSubviewAtIndex:(NSInteger)index2;
- (void)bringSubviewToFront:(UIView *)view;
- (void)sendSubviewToBack:(UIView *)view;
```

And Many more..
Regards,
Neil.